# What does "call somebody's bluff" mean (in the context)?

Tags: meaning, expressions, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, books

I can't understand the meaning of this expression in the context.

> ‘Granddad was saying he was good for nothing, every badness was possible with him, but he didn’t drink and never had, so at least there was that one thing, one thing only that could nearly be seen as a good thing. My father called his dead bluff. I walked him home from his last session. I haven’t a bob left now, he said, and if we went over this minute to my father’s grave and dug him up, he’d be face down inside in the coffin.’
>
> *(Donal Ryan ‘The Spinning Heart’).*

So, as I get it the grandfather said that the only thing the father will not do is to become a drunkard, and in order to spite him, the father drank out the farm, and by doing so, he called the grandfather’s dead bluff.

I've read various definitions of the expression ‘to call somebody’s bluff’, but still nothing makes sense to me.

How can I paraphrase this sentence?

Can it mean something like:

> My dad accepted the challenge of his dad.

Or:

> My dad fooled his dad.

Or something completely different?

Comment: Not the greatest metaphor, but... Grandfather strongly maintained (effectively, ***bet***) that despite being almost totally worthless, ***at least*** his son would never drink excessively. But that was just bluff and bluster - the son (narrator's father) "called the bluff" (and gave the lie to it) by drinking so much he lost his farm (which would have metaphorically had the grandfather turning in his grave).

Comment: to call someone's bluff: to challenge someone to carry out a threat: *If she thinks she can threaten us with firing us all, I think it's time we called her bluff.​* See: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/called-trump%e2%80%99s-bluff.3239563/

Comment: @Greybeard So unless there's a broadened meaning here, the bluff-caller must believe that dead men are still able to deliver on earlier threats. And in any case, no overt threat is stated here. The question hinges then on the acceptability of the author's broadening the meaning of 'call someone's bluff'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth *So unless there's a broadened meaning here, the bluff-caller must believe that dead men are still able to deliver on earlier threats.* I'm not sure I follow. The threat is of of a future of being "good for nothing" + a parenthetical *although he does not drink.* hangs over him after the death of his father. We expect that the threat will strengthen his character and he will become successful so as to defy his father. It turns out that he defies his father by drinking.

Comment: @Greybeard 'to call someone's bluff: to challenge someone to carry out a threat'. Not 'to defy someone, however belatedly'. Challenges are presented to the living, unless we're abandoning the strict sense.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think you need to see what was, apparently, the motivation of the father. His bluff in achieving his goal (making his son a better person in his eyes) relied upon a reaction. OED Bluff: *"challenging or boastful language or demeanour, not intended to be carried out, but merely ‘tried on’ with the design of frightening or influencing an opponent who allows himself to be imposed upon by it."*

Comment: @Greybeard I've no problem with the broadened usage. But 'to call someone's bluff: to challenge someone to carry out a threat' only allows for the direct confrontation of two parties.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't think it does: ***A:*** "Before he died, my husband said he would come back and haunt me if I remarried." ***B:*** "Get married - call his bluff."

Comment: 'To challenge someone to carry out a threat' means face to face. Time to quit.